# List months between dates and display accross columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a really simple script that shows 3 component catalog numbers and their new release dates ...

```
        SELECT nrb.p_catnr,
               (
                   select min(selection_relse_date) 
                     from BDS_SELECTION_ORG@sid_to_cdsuk st 
                    where substr(selection_no, 2, 99) = pd.catnr
               ) NR_DATE
          FROM part_description pd 
    INNER JOIN inventory_purchase ip 
            ON ip.part_no = pd.part_no 
    INNER JOIN scm_prodtyp pt 
            ON pt.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp 
    INNER JOIN oes_fod_match acp 
            ON acp.part_no = pd.part_no 
    INNER JOIN NCF_COMPPART ncf 
            ON ncf.item_part_no = pd.part_no 
    INNER JOIN oes_nrbom nrb 
            ON ncf.catnr = nrb.c_catnr 
           AND ncf.prodtyp = nrb.c_prodtyp 
           AND ncf.packtyp = nrb.c_packtyp 
           AND ncf.vernr = nrb.c_vernr 
         WHERE pd.cunr in ('649830', 'W30000') 
           AND pd.catnr = '2EDVD0017' 
           AND pd.fod_idc = 'Y' 
           AND pt.prodgrp = 'AW'
```

Result as follows...

[image]

What I would like to add is a list of every month & year (MON-YYYY) from the NR_DATE to current date but, I would like to add this horizontally, i.e.

[image]

Then I would like to add the following script...

```
(select nvl(sum(dp.del_qty),0) 
   from bds_dhead@sid_to_cdsuk dh, 
        bds_dline@sid_to_cdsuk dp 
  where dp.dhead_no = dh.dhead_no 
    and dh.d_status = '9' 
    and dp.article_no = '9'||nrb.p_catnr 
    and to_char(dh.actshpdate,'MON-YYYY') = --'list of months'
```

and plot the sums in the correct column/row.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What version of sql are you using?

Comment: Entirely possible. You should look at PIVOT

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm connecting to OraClient11g, using 'Toad for Oracle' to develop the script and then Business Objects 5.1 to run the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use SQL for such tasks. SQL operates on data level, but you want to do things on presentation level.

So you design your SQL, that it returns the result set as rows and then you use your favorite reporting tool, to make a pivot table from the data. You can use Eclipse BIRT, Crystal Reports or even excel to do such things.

**Edit:**

Of course some RDBMS also support pivot tables in their SQL language. But there are good reasons to separate data and presentation layer.